# @JsonProperty Json object inside Json object

Tags: java, json, jackson

How do I use the @JsonProperty() to get a json object within another json object? The example json I want to get is:

```
"location" : {
  "needs_recoding" : false,
  "longitude" : "-94.35281245682333",
  "latitude" : "35.35363522126198",
  "human_address" : "{\"address\":\"7301 ROGERS AVE\",\"city\":\"FORT SMITH\",\"state\":\"AR\",\"zip\":\"\"}"
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that you're working with?  You may not need any annotation, just an appropriate bean reference in the property.

Comment: I'm using it in a constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A helpful reference](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html) for using [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotations in a constructor is provided by [StaxMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59501/staxman). A simple example shown below:

```
public class Address {
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    // Constructors, getters/setters
}

public class Location {
    private boolean needsRecoding;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;
    private Address humanAddress;

    public Location() {
        super();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Location(
        @JsonProperty("needs_recoding") boolean needsRecoding,
        @JsonProperty("longitude") Double longitude,
        @JsonProperty("latitude") Double latitude,
        @JsonProperty("human_address") Address humanAddress) {

        super();
        this.needsRecoding = needsRecoding;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.humanAddress = humanAddress;
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

Alternately, you may deserialize content directly into a JSON object tree. Illustrated below with a slight modification of the `Location` class example:

```
public class Location {
    private boolean needsRecoding;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double latitude;

    // Note the use of JsonNode, as opposed to an explicitly created POJO
    private JsonNode humanAddress;

    public Location() {
        super();
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Location(
        @JsonProperty("needs_recoding") boolean needsRecoding,
        @JsonProperty("longitude") Double longitude,
        @JsonProperty("latitude") Double latitude,
        @JsonProperty("human_address") JsonNode humanAddress) {

        super();
        this.needsRecoding = needsRecoding;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.humanAddress = humanAddress;
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to get the Json Object contained in location without creating a location class?

Comment: @Hank - you can deserialize data directly into a [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). See edits to my answer for an example.